# How to get CResamplerMediaObject to work as it is supposed to?

Tags: windows, audio, ms-media-foundation, dmo

I am trying to use [CResamplerMediaObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/audioresampler) to resample audio I capture from the DefaultAudioEndpoint in order to clone it to any other AudioEndpoint I choose.

But whatever the Input/OutputType is, it seems to just pass through what I input to it without modification.

If the Input/OutputType look like this:

```
inputType()
 WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE:
    wFormatTag = 65534
    cbSize = 22
    nAvgBytesPerSec = 384000
    nBlockAlign = 8
    nChannels = 2
    nSamplesPerSec = 48000
    wBitsPerSample = 32
    ext->dwChannelMask = 3
    ext->Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = 32
    ext->Samples.wSamplesPerBlock = 32
    ext->SubFormat = {00000003-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}

 Properties of the media type: 
    MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS = 2
    MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND = 48000
    MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT = 8
    MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND = 384000
    MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 32
    MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT = 1
    MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK = 3
    MF_MT_AUDIO_VALID_BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 0

outputType()
 WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE:
    wFormatTag = 65534
    cbSize = 22
    nAvgBytesPerSec = 1536000
    nBlockAlign = 32
    nChannels = 8
    nSamplesPerSec = 48000
    wBitsPerSample = 32
    ext->dwChannelMask = 1599
    ext->Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = 32
    ext->Samples.wSamplesPerBlock = 32
    ext->SubFormat = {00000003-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}

 Properties of the media type:
    MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS = 8
    MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND = 48000
    MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT = 32
    MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND = 1536000
    MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 32
    MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT = 1
    MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK = 1599
    MF_MT_AUDIO_VALID_BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 0
```

I would expect to get for every input frame with length of 8 Bytes ( ( wBitsPerSample / 8 ) * nChannels) an output frame with a length of 32 Bytes. Instead the outputframes are still 8 Bytes long.

If I insert the missing 6 bytes in the output data it works as expected, but would this not be the job of the resampler?

Also if I change the sampling rate for input or output I would expect to see changes in length between the inputed and outputed data. But it remains the same.

You can find the source code [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5d1ba482edea2bf).
If somebody needs an working example program it is available [here](https://github.com/Markus87/CloneWhatYouHear).

Comment: The DMO/MFT is known to work, you're likely doing something wrong

Comment: Yeah. =) I figured as much, but I just cant figure out what I did miss to make it behave in that unhelpful way. (I am going to attach the code, I hope no one gets sick)

Comment: `SetOutputType( 0, inputType(), ...` in line 247?

Comment: Thank you @RomanR. It is so helpful to have new eyes sometimes. I likely never would have spotted this stupid copy/paste error. Now it works just as expected.
If you post your suggestion I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of input media type twice is a likely cause and matches the behavior you are describing:

```
Check( transform()->SetInputType( 0, inputType(), 0 ), "transform()->SetInputType" );
Check( transform()->SetOutputType( 0, inputType(), 0 ), "transform()->SetOutputType" );
```